# c# how can i add constraint in my code

Tags: c#

i have written following code to calculate the total of entrance fees to a park based on the user’s age. The code is running prefectly. i want to add one more feature that if the user enters the value of the age < 0; give 2 more chances for the user to enter the correct value for age (value for age must be >= 0). An error message, Invalid…, will appear after 3 attempts and the program will print Thank You and terminate. i dont need someone to write code, I need an idea where and how i can implement this feature in my code.

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        string username;
        int password, count=0 , num_guest , age;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Username : ");
            username = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            Console.Write("Password : ");
             password = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

             if (password.Equals(63100))
             {
                 Console.Clear();
                 Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + username);
                 Console.Write("Enter number of guests : ");
                 num_guest = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                 if (num_guest <= 0)
                 {
                     Console.Clear();
                     Console.WriteLine("Thank You");
                     Environment.Exit(0);
                 }
                     else
                 {

                     for (int j = 1; j <num_guest+1; j++)
                     {
                         Console.Write("Enter age of "+j+" guest : ");
                         age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                             if (age >= 0)
                             {
                                 if (age == 0 && age == 1)
                                 {
                                     count = count + 0;
                                 }
                                 else if (age >= 2 && age <= 17)
                                 {
                                     count = count + 60;
                                 }

                                 else if (age >= 18 && age <= 59)
                                 {
                                     count = count + 35;
                                 }

                                 else if (age > 60)
                                 {
                                     count = count + 30;
                                 }
                               }

                     }

                     Console.WriteLine(count);
                     Console.ReadLine();

                 }

                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password!");
             }
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Bye..." );
        Environment.Exit(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a loop together with a counter, increment the counter every time `age <= 0`.
At the start of the loop, check if counter is 3, then print error message and exit.

Otherwise, if everything is ok, `break;` from the `while` loop.

```
int counter = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (counter == 3) {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank You");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (age > 0)
        break;
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop with a counter, when it reaches 0 terminate or break out when the user entered a valid age

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string username;
    int password, count=0 , num_guest , age;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Username : ");
        username = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        Console.Write("Password : ");
         password = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         if (password.Equals(63100))
         {
             Console.Clear();
             Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + username);
             Console.Write("Enter number of guests : ");
             num_guest = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

             if (num_guest <= 0)
             {
                 Console.Clear();
                 Console.WriteLine("Thank You");
                 Environment.Exit(0);
             }
                 else
             {
                 //make counter here 
                 for (int j = 1; j <num_guest+1; j++)
                 {
                     Console.Write("Enter age of "+j+" guest : ");
                     age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                         if (age >= 0)
                         {
                             //reset counter here
                             if (age == 0 && age == 1)
                             {
                                 count = count + 0;
                             }
                             else if (age >= 2 && age <= 17)
                             {
                                 count = count + 60;
                             }

                             else if (age >= 18 && age <= 59)
                             {
                                 count = count + 35;
                             }

                             else if (age > 60)
                             {
                                 count = count + 30;
                             }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            // minus 1 of j  increment counter here if counter hits 3 then ouput message then terminate program
                         }

                 }

                 Console.WriteLine(count);
                 Console.ReadLine();

             }

             break;
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password!");
         }
    }

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Bye..." );
    Environment.Exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you read and parse the age input, you can use a `while` loop to validate it, and if it's invalid ask for it again.

```
Console.Write("Enter age of "+j+" guest : ");
age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int tries = 0;
while (age < 0)
{
    if (tries >= MAX_TRIES)
       return;
    else
       ++tries;

    Console.WriteLine("Age must be zero or a positive number");
    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should begin to break up your code into seperate methods to improve readability. One could be named ReadValidAge and returns -1 if the user has not entered a valid age in 3 tries. something like:

```
 private static int ReadValidAge(int guestNumber)
 {
      int result;
      for(int i = 3; i > 0;)
      {
          Console.Write("Enter Age of guest {0}: ", guestNumber);
          if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out result) && result > 0)
          {
              return result;
          }
          else
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Invalid Age entered ... {0} Tries left!", --i); 
          }
      }
      return -1;
 }
```

Then you call it and branch with an if statement out of the program:

```
  for (int j = 1; j <num_guest+1; j++)
  {
      age = ReadValidAge(j);
      if(age == -1)
      {
          //Say byebye here

          return;
      }
      // your orignal code
```